# How to search git repo history for a quoted string?

Tags: regex, git, shell

I can search git commit history for a string, but how do I search for a quoted string? This is how I search for a string:

```
git grep "some text here" $(git rev-list --all)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use single quotes:

```
git grep '"string"' ...
```

Comment: Note that this is due to the shell you are using, not due to Git itself. For all commonly-used shells such as `bash`, both `''` and `""` are strings that can contain the other quote character. Git itself just sees that it is passed a string argument `"string"` – it won’t know that you surrounded the input in quotes in the calling program.